# Verify command successfully executes over ssh in BASH

Tags: bash, ssh, chmod

How does one verify that linux command is successfully executed over the ssh server? See the following example

```
ssh -qX 10.10.1.123 chmod -R 755 someDir/
```

I know that using the return code (0 or 1) method works but there are instances where the above command executes but the permissions do NOT get changed. Is there a better way to verify whether it executed successfully and permissions are changed accordingly?

Comment: Does `chmod` itself have the same problem "where the above command executes but the permissions do NOT get changed", without it being reflected in exit status?

Comment: ...to be clear: If `chmod` itself still has that problem, I don't think this has any reason to be a question about `ssh`; all you care about is detecting whether the chmod problem happened, and whether it's local or remote is immaterial.

Comment: (btw, why `ssh -X`? You aren't running a GUI application here)

Comment: What are the scenarios where `ssh` returns a success status even tough the command failed? I can't think of any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no *generic* answer, because there's no generic problem. `ssh` does not return success to the caller unless the remote child gave a successful result.

For the *specific* problem, assuming your remote machine has a version of chmod that can incorrectly return unwarranted successful exit statuses, one might use:

```
if [[ $(ssh 10.10.1.123 'find someDir/ ! -perm 755 -print -quit') ]]; then
  echo "At least one file under someDir did not have its permissions changed to 755" >&2
fi
```